# prisma import fails to import relation tables with error: Failure inserting into relationtable

Tags: postgresql, import, database-migration, prisma, prisma-graphql

When trying to import data into a postgres database with prisma CLI's `prisma import --data export.<DATE>.zip` it fails with an error for all relations in the postgresql database:

I have to run `prisma deploy` first to make sure the schema is updated but when it imports the data it is trying to import the relations twice which is violating some sort of duplicate constraint.

```sh
 "Failure inserting into relationtable _ExampleForOtherExample with ids StringIdGCValue(ckamscvpi0eo00702ep0c7log) and StringIdGCValue(cka2n025p03ri0766hnoyxf8s). Cause: insert or update on table \"_ExampleForOtherExample\" violates foreign key econstraint \"_ExampleForOtherExample_A_fkey\"\n  Detail: Key (A)=(cjvba054700dz07236tafuscj) is not present in table \"Example\".",
"Failure inserting into relationtable _ThingToOtherThing with ids StringIdGCValue(ckbgyi96h0kl1079500z24pwu) and StringIdGCValue(ckbkvgde606s50855g62uhqsb). Cause: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"_ThingToOtherThing_AB_unique\"\n  Detail: Key (\"A\", \"B\")=(ck3kbmjgl036x0788furaqxkg, ck6uvgy7o09p40723rw34tna1) already exists.",
```

I'm not sure why it imports everything except for relations.

(prisma version 1.30.5)

Comment: As a work-around I was able to use pg_dump and pg_restore instead of prisma export and prisma import. But prisma import failed every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tldr;

prisma1 export creates duplicate relation table row data in their export data that are not present in the origin data. The error can be solved by removing those duplicates.

#### More Details

I found out that when I use the `prisma1 export` command, it creates duplicate relation table rows in its exported json files. My source database did not have these duplicates but they get introduced into the exported files.

I created a simple node script that parsed all the JSON files and printed out all the duplicate relation row column A IDs.

With this data I carefully removed all the duplicates `prisma1 export` command created in my data. Once I did this, this error went away and I was able to use `prisma1 import` without issue.

Comment: Where is such a script?

Comment: I don't have the script anymore sadly but I basically looped through the key value pairs in each json file (each of which represented a row) using a node script and added them to an empty array and if any row matched a row in the array I removed it. In this way all duplicates were removed.

Comment: I found the script and put it in a gist: https://gist.github.com/inlightmedia/3cbf08918f3c4bcd474be73a9b5991ec

Here is the related github issue and my answer there: https://github.com/prisma/prisma1/issues/4216#issuecomment-925544248

Answer (score 0):

You have foreign key dependencies between the tables, and your imported data don't satisfy the constraints.

Either import the data in an order that doesn't violate the constraints, or drop the constraints in the database and create them again after the import.

You could dump all the constraints with

```
pg_dump --section=post-data databasename
```

Comment: I'm assuming the dump is saving a copy. How would you drop the constraints? Then how would you create them again after the import?

Comment: You drop them by running a bunch of `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT ...`, and you create them again by restoring the dump I suggested you make.

Comment: When I try `ALTER TABLE "MyTable" DROP CONSTRAINT "MyConstraint_AB_unique";` it says the constraint does not exist on that table. However, when I run `/d+ "MyTable";` it lists that constraint verbatim as one of the constraints on that table. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Could be a copy-and-paste error, a missing schema qualification, or you are connected to the wrong database.

Answer (score 0):

I had luck importing data after removing the `.import/` folder

https://github.com/prisma/prisma1/issues/4216#issuecomment-513104926

Comment: This didn't work in my case but I'm glad it worked in your case!